# Add easing to UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration

Tags: ios, animation, easing, easing-functions

Im using

```
UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration
```

and i have 3 animation sections using

```
[UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime
```

However, on one of the key frames I want to easeIn.

How can I add an easing function to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trustworthy article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html
You will have to deal with `CAAnimation`, not just `UIView`.

Update:
As the PO didn't make it so far, there are some catches on what could go wrong:
**a) Make sure that your animation is created and added like follows:**

```
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
[theLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];

// Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value.
theLayer.opacity = 0.0;
```

For more details see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

**b) When you use** `animateTransition:`, **make sure that**:

> All animations must take place in the view specified by the
>   containerView property of transitionContext.

(visit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning/animateTransition: for reference). Hope this will help you sort all the issues out.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that conclusion too. However, I'm adding my CABasicAnimations to the layer within animateTransition: and it's not running them!

Comment: Please see the updates on my answer - I described some possible reasons of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Point b looks like an interesting note. I'll look into this further.